# Regex: Match and delete a particular word or sign like " | " from a particular meta tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have 2 scenario.

First one, I have to delete the operator `|` from a particular meta tag:

`<meta name="keywords" content="Enough place to shelter | Love Is everywhere"/>`

Made a regex, not too good..

FIND: `(?:<meta name="keywords" content="|)\w+\K\h+\||(?=.*?/>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\2`

And the second scenario, I have to delete a particular word from a particular meta tag, such as:

`<meta name="keywords" content="I have to but something WORD_TO_DELETE  from here | Love me"/>`

I also update a little bit the first regex, but is not too good.

FIND: `(?:<meta name="keywords" content="|)\w+\K(WORD_TO_DELETE)(?=.*?/>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1\2`

Comment: Please, give the expected result for both case.

Comment: Please only one question per ... question;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question (for the second one, please ask a new question):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<meta name="keywords" content="|\G)[^|"]*\K\|\h*`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                                 #  non capture group
    <meta name="keywords" content="     # literally
  |                                   # OR
    \G                                  # restart from last match position
)                                   # end group
[^|"]*                              # 0 or more any character that is not pipe or double quote
\K                                  # forget all we have seen until this position
\|                                  # a pipe
\h*                                 # 0 or more horizontal space
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]